# Good Single User Open Source Persistant Database that's easy to install and works with Open Office Base?

Tags: database, open-source, openoffice.org, single-user

I'm creating a program for end-users, that's already written using MySQL and some OpenOffice.org Star Basic Macros.  I was wondering if there was an open source single user database that would be easy enough for the average Joe to install, (or that I could write a macro to install it for him...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenOffice.org Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Base) Wikipedia article briefly describes the database module in openoffice.

> OpenOffice.org users, however, can choose to connect to external full-featured SQL database such as MySQL, PostgreSQL and even Oracle through ODBC or JDBC drivers. **OpenOffice.org Base can hence act as a GUI frontend for SQL views, table design and query**.

A simple, single-user database library that needs no install is [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite),
that had been considered by the openoffice team.
It is used in many mainline applications, e.g. [Mozilla Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox).

Comment: Okay the concensious seemed to be SQLite, I'll have to give it a shot. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the one built into [OpenOffice](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid39_gci1148271,00.html) 2?

***Update***

Okay, more details.  The database product is called, simply, [Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html).  It's *both* a front-end and provides a local database: it provides [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) for local databases, and it supports a whole raft of other databases like MySQL:

> For power users in the enterprise,
>   BASE delivers native support drivers
>   for a variety of multi-user database
>   engines: MySQL, Adabas D, MS Access
>   and PostgreSQL. In addition, support
>   for JDBC and ODBC standard drivers
>   allows you to connect to virtually any
>   existing database.

Comment: I didn't know there was one built in...what's it called?  It's not HSQL is it?

Comment: I thought Ooo Base was just a front-end.

Comment: Which one is built into OpenOffice 2?

Comment: HSQL is built in, but you can also access others.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you would specify the target OS. Though, the "easy enough for the average Joe to install" bit suggests Windows. :-)

If my guess is right, have you looked at [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx)? There are couple of features that might actually meet your needs:

- Free to use and distribute
- No administration required
- Single file, code free database format
- Support for ClickOnce, XCopy, MSI, CAB, and non-admin embedded installation options
- less than 2 MB of files to deploy and with no dependencies on back-end services

If the name Microsoft by itself is enough to give you nightmares, there's also the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) server. I personaly have not used it and can't vouch how good it is. However, it is backed by big names like Adobe, Mozilla and Symbian, so I would assume it should be good enough for you needs too.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) will likely fit the bill. Very simple, very simple to install, very popular and stable.